# Tip in a SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have a small project where I need to display all restaurants that a user didn't visit yet. I have 3 tables

- `RestaurantTable`
- `PersonTable`
- `VisitTable`

`Visit` table is a join table for restaurant and person with columns

```
id, person_id, restaurant_id, Date
```

What query can I use to return the restaurants that are not visited yet?

Please note that if a restaurant is visited, it is added to the `VisitTable` otherwise it won't be inserted into the `VisitTable`. I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Restaurants LEFT JOIN Visits USING (restaurant_id) WHERE Visits.restaurant_id IS NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select *
from restaurants r
where not exists (select 1 from visits v where v.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id)
```

For performance, you want an index on `visits(restaurant_id)`; if you have a properly declared foreign key, it should exist already.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the RestaurantTable contains restaurant_id column, you can use the following code:

```
select restaurant_id from RestaurantTable
where restaurant_id not in (select distinct restaurant_id from VisitTable)
```